# How to avoid reinstallation of new driver package and use WebDriverManager package for selenium automation test

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, ui-automation

How to avoid reinstallation of the new driver package and use WebDriverManager package for selenium automation test?

Answer (score 0):

ChromeDriver version is not compatible with the installed Chrome Browser. Please update ChromeDriver to the appropriate version." or "No browser window is open, so navigation cannot continue." message is shown when Chrome browser and Selenium driver (a selenium driver used to interact with browser to perform automation) is incompatible. Google releases the new version for chrome browser at regular interval and the auto-update browser settings result in this sort of incompatibility between the browser and the driver version present

Problem 1: To run our test cases on chrome/IE browser we need to install driver packages. We do it using manage nuget packages:
[image]

Once we install this package it copies chromedriver.exe in debug folder. If we don’t do this it will not be able to find chromedriver.exe and will not be able to run the test cases.
Problem 2: The second problem is with the browser version. If the browser version changes we again need to update our chromedriver.

Solution: But this problem can be easily solved using web driver manager api package. Based on the browser version present in the system WebDriverManager API will download the driver executable.

1. Install WebDriverManager from NuGet.

[image]

2. We need to initialize the driver using the following code:

   New DriverManager().SetUpDriver(new ChromeConfig());
   IwebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();

•   ChromeConfig()- To spacify default configuration for chrome browser.
•   We can use FirefoxConfig() for firefox browser.
Now if you run the test it will not need an external chrome driver download. You can get more information related to webmangerdriver from the below location:

[WebDriverAPI Help](https://github.com/rosolko/WebDriverManager.Net)